# Cannot get correct timestamp on xaxis in highchart-charts in angular

Tags: angular, highcharts

I checked the unix timestamp and it seems to be right but I can't figure out why it keeps showing me 11:xx:xx. It's not 11, tried it different time throughout the day. I'm using the `highchart-charts` for angular

Ive tried many things,listed here:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    time: {
        timezone: 'America/New_York' // also tried 5*60 for time offset
    }
});
```

My setup

```
chartOptions: Object = {
          chart: {
              type: 'area',
            },
            tooltip: {
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                  hour: '%A, %b %e, %l %p'
                },
              },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title : ""
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                min:moment().tz('America/New_York').hour(9).minute(25).valueOf()/1000,
                max:moment().tz('America/New_York').hour(16).minute(5).valueOf()/1000,
              },
          series: [{
              data: []
          }]
  };
```

and my data retrieval,

```
    interval(60000).pipe(
              startWith(0),
              mergeMap(() => this.realtimeChartService.get_realtime({symbol : this.symbol })),
              takeUntil(take(1))
           ).subscribe(data => {
                   const data = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
                   const last = data[data.length -1 ];
                   const last_format = this.formatData([last])
//formatData does something like this
//moment(data[j]["date"] +' '+ data[j]["minute"]).tz('America/New_York').valueOf()/1000,
                   this.chartOptions.series[0].addPoint(last_format[0], true, shift);
           });
```

here's some output, also tried multiply/divide 102, 100s =/

```
[1595856600, 1499.846]
[1595856660, 1442.314]
[1595856720, 1422.673]
[1595856780, 1456.018]
[1595856840, 1467.572]
[1595856900, 1485.134]
[1595856960, 1426.85]
[1595857020, 1473.908]
[1595857080, 1451.796]
[1595857140, 1473.079]
[1595857200, 1496.399]
```

Comment: The `time.timezone` requires the moment.js library. Are you sure that you imported it and assigned it to the `window.moment`? I was trying to reproduce the issue but in my case, the chart handled it correctly. Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-3ysvvx

Comment: @MateuszKornecki hmm, but the time on your chart now shows 6am, 1595856600 refers to 07/27/2020 @ 1:30pm (UTC) though

Comment: Could you tell me what is your expected output? Correct me if I am wrong but as far as I know the UTC for `1595856600` is actually equal to 11:17:36.  NY has the UTC -5 time, 11:17 - 5:00 = `6:17`. ```new Date(1595856600).toUTCString()
"Mon, 19 Jan 1970 11:17:36 GMT"``` Am I missing something?